# How to set the RBFOpt Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on feature selection.  I was reading that the  RBFOpt package is one way to optimise feature selection.

The following is a copy of the code I am using.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from rbfopt import RbfoptUserBlackBox, RbfoptSettings, RbfoptAlgorithm

# Define the target variable column
target_col = 'Outcome_Sold' 

# Define the objective function for RBFOpt
def objective_function(features):
    X = df[features].values
    y = df[target_col].values
    model = RandomForestRegressor()
    model.fit(X, y)
    return -model.score(X, y)  # Minimize negative R^2 score

# Define the lower and upper bounds for the feature selection
lower_bound = [0] * 10  
upper_bound = [1] * 10  

# Define the variable types as continuous for all features
var_type = ['C'] * 10  

# Create the RBFOpt black-box user function
black_box = RbfoptUserBlackBox(10, lower_bound, upper_bound, var_type, 
obj_funct=objective_function)

# Set RBFOpt options
settings = RbfoptSettings()
settings.algorithm_class = RbfoptAlgorithm.MSRSM
```

df contains 10 prediction features and an outcome variable called 'Outcome_Sold'.  When I run the code I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14624\1637864.py in <module>
     26 # Set RBFOpt options
     27 settings = RbfoptSettings()
---> 28 settings.algorithm_class = RbfoptAlgorithm.MSRSM
     29 settings.num_global_search = 50
     30 settings.num_rbf = 500

AttributeError: type object 'RbfoptAlgorithm' has no attribute 'MSRSM'
```

I have tried different RbfoptAlgorithm options including RbfoptAlgorithm.DIRECT, RbfoptAlgorithm.GA

All methods return the same type of error.

Is there another way to set the algorithm class?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://rbfopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rbfopt_algorithm.html), it makes sense to get an error in all your attempts, since none of those attributes are there, see also the [source](https://rbfopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/rbfopt_algorithm.html#RbfoptAlgorithm).

If you run:

```
import rbfopt

print(dir(rbfopt.RbfoptAlgorithm))
```

you'll get (where I didn't include the `__*` ones):

```
[..., 'add_node', 'add_noisy_node', 'advance_step_counter', 'load_from_file', 'optimize', 'optimize_parallel', 'optimize_serial', 'phase_update', 'print_init_line', 'print_summary_line', 'refinement_update', 'refinement_update_parallel', 'remove_existing_nodes', 'remove_node', 'require_accurate_evaluation', 'restart', 'restoration_search', 'save_to_file', 'set_output_stream', 'stalling_update', 'unlimited_refinement_active', 'update_log']
```

In case you haven't seen it already, take a look at this [minimal working example](https://github.com/coin-or/rbfopt#minimal-working-example), meaning, that without setting the algorithm class, you would do:

```
...
# Set RBFOpt options
settings = RbfoptSettings()

alg = rbfopt.RbfoptAlgorithm(settings, black_box)
val, x, itercount, evalcount, fast_evalcount = alg.optimize()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. So I take it that RbfoptAlgorithm does not specify the algorithm per se.  Does it need to be set per se or will it run a default if omitted?

Comment: From the minimal example linked in my answer @JohnH I understand that default settings will be used in this case. However, I haven't really used this module in real life.